# Noty (notifier) is not working inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, notifications

I have a misterious problem with the noty plugin [click](http://needim.github.com/noty/). When I create a notifier as explained on the site everything works fine, but when I put the same statement into a function which is called at the "onClick" event from a button, it doesn't work. There is no noty-notification coming, no errors, nothing happens if I press the button. When I remove the noty-thing and add a normal "alert" statement everything works fine. Is there something I have missed or is this a bug?

The original code looks like:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/noty/jquery.noty.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/noty/layouts/top.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/noty/themes/default.js"></script>
</head>
...
<script>
var noty = noty({text: 'noty - a jquery notification library!'});
</script>
```

When I put the same statement into following function, noty don't works anymore.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/noty/jquery.noty.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/noty/layouts/top.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/noty/themes/default.js"></script>
</head>
...
<a href="#" onclick="test_function(); return false;" class="btn">klick</a>
...
<script>
function test_function(){
   var noty = noty({text: 'noty - a jquery notification library!'});
}
</script>
```

Even if I change the `var noty` to `var n` (or something else) nothing changes, as stated in one stackoverflow question before.

Thanks in advance.
Regards, john.

Comment: Please expand on the "it doesn't work" part :) Any error messages? Browser crashes? Black holes?

Comment: no error, no browser crash. it is doing nothing when i click the button (like i don't have an "onclick" event). when i remove the noty-thing and insert a normal "alert" statement, everything works fine...

Comment: ok. i've tested it now with a complete new and plain html file. it works when you give the variable another name as "noty". in my example above it don't works even with a new variable-name, but now i know it has something to do with my other code (or plugins, or css, etc.). i could test that in the evening when i'm at home. regards.

Comment: Well, of course `var noty = noty(...);` does not work because `noty` refers to the variable you just declared and it is `undefined`. You *do* get the error `undefined is not a function` or something similar. Renaming `var notify` to `var n` works perfectly fine: http://jsfiddle.net/FPQQp/. *edit:* Wow, sometimes my browser really does not refresh :)

Answer (score 3):

it would be better if you use something like this:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/noty/jquery.noty.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/noty/layouts/top.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/noty/themes/default.js"></script>
</head>

<script>
$("#element").click(function(){
   var n = noty({text: 'noty - a jquery notification library!'});
});
</script>

<a id="element" href="#" onclick="return false;" class="btn">klick</a>
```

And of course use an "id" on the element you wish to bind to noty.  It will work perfectly.

Check out working example here:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FPQQp/1/)

Comment: Did this answer solve your issue? Curious to know how it went.  Cheers.